# C++ Перегрузка оператора '+' в собственном строковом классе

Tags: c++, указатели, перегрузка-операторов

```
CAbout CAbout::operator+(const CAbout& str)
{
   CAbout dopstr;
   dopstr.m_length = this->m_length + str.m_length - 1;
   dopstr.m_strok = new char[dopstr.m_length];
   for (size_t i{0}; i < this->m_length; i++)
   {
       *(dopstr.m_strok + i) = *(this->m_strok + i);
   }
   for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < str.m_length + 1; i++)
   {
       dopstr.m_strok[i + this->m_length] = str.m_strok[i];
   }
   return dopstr;
}
```

Сам класс выглядит след. образом

```
class CAbout
{
public:
CAbout(const char* str = "Standart str");
CAbout(const CAbout& str);
~CAbout();
CAbout& operator=(const CAbout& str);
CAbout operator+(const CAbout& str);
void show();

private:
char* m_strok;
size_t m_length;
};
```

Интересует функций оператора +, все остальные функции работают хорошо. Интересует даже не столько, как написать правильный рабочий код, а то, почему 1-ый цикл for в функции оператора + работает хорошо, а второй цикл проходит, но ничего не изменяет. Строка класса dopstr принимает значение this->m_strok в первом цикле и дальше никак не изменяется. В чем проблема ?

Comment: Я что-то не пойму, почему память выделяется для суммы длин без единицы, а суммарное число итераций циклов - сумма длин плюс единица?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, `m_length` у вас учитывает и нулевой символ строки тоже. Тогда все очевидно - просто второй цикл начинает писать **после** нулевого символа.

Comment: А разве он не перезаписывает нулевой символ первой строки ?

Comment: @Сеня  Давайте пусть первый - "Сеня", второй - ну, неважно пока. `m_length` равна 5. Запись первой строки в НОВЫЙ массив - все 5 символов. Теперь второй цикл начинает с записи в какой элемент? Правильно, `0+m_length = 5`, т.е. в ШЕСТОЙ. ПОСЛЕ нулевого. И, кстати, у вас получается еще и выход за границы массива, так что если программа не падает сразу - это можно считать невезением - значит, свалится в какой-то отдаленной точке...

Comment: Теперь понял. Спасибо